# Simply connected domain (Homotopy)

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me showing that :

For any simply connected plain domain $D_1, D_2 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ where $ D_1 \cap D_2 \neq \phi$ is connected, show that $D_1 \cup D_2$ and $D_1 \cap D_2$ are simply connected.

The restriction is I have to use homotopy notion. That is, a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is simply connected if every continuous closed curve is homotopic to a point $z \in D$.

I have no idea about this since homotopy is very new to me.

Comment: Domain as connected open?

Comment: Yes, $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a domain if $D$ is open and connected.

Comment: Note that this question appears in complex analysis course, but the definition for simply connected domain somehow goes beyond what I expect to face in complex analysis. I think that homotopy is very deep notion in topology.

Comment: Oh, I do not know there is an answer. I will try reading it from the link.

Comment: @nullUser I follow the link, but I do not find the solution. Actually, I am not sure, but there are some suggestions about proving with different definition of simply connected domain. So I suppose that the solution does not use definition of homotopy.

Comment: @YotasTrejos If you question about some other notions besides the domain, please ask me. I can write them in full if you need. Thank you. I hope that I just do not bother you too much.

Answer (score 0):

For union take a loop $f:I\rightarrow D_1\cup D_2$  on a point $x_0\in D_1\cap D_2$. Then the collection $\{f^{-1}(D_1), f^{-1}(D_1)\}$  covers $I$ and the you can get a pair of intervals $[0,t], [t,1]$ such that $f[0,t]\subset D_1$ and $f[t,1]\subset D_2$. Trace a curve $\gamma$ with initial point $x_{0}$ and finally point $f(t)$. Then you have that $[f]=[f_1f_2]=[f_1\bar\gamma\gamma f_2]=[f_1\bar\gamma][\gamma f_2]=[\text{constant path}] $. Since $f_1\bar\gamma\subset D_1$ and $\gamma f_2\subset D_2$

Here $f_1=f\upharpoonright[0,t]$, $f_2=f\upharpoonright[t,1]$.

I don't know yet how to do it for the intersection.

What I have did it easier to understand with a picture.

Do you understand the idea of this demonstration?

Comment: I think I do not get it. At least, please clarify some notations like $[f], [f_1 [0,t]f_2], f \upharpoonright$. It does go beyond what I expect indeed. I think that I just need to define a continuous function stated in the homotopy definition. Anyway, what do you mean by loop ? You mean closed path ? Sorry that I ask too much. It is really very new to me, and the text provide barely nothing except the very abstract definition of homotopy.

Comment: The notion of homotopy is not too abstract, it just a way to say that you can move one curve to the other continuosly. I don't know a simpler way to prove that. I belive that an explicit homotopy have to very hard to find. What book are you using to learn complex analysis?

Comment: The harpoon means the restriction of  f to the set after the harpoon. The brackets means equivalence class.

Comment: I use complex analysis in spirit of Lipman Bers. It is a good book, I guess, for one who has a very rigorous and intense background in analysis and complex variables. It is also quite abstract. I have some background in complex variables, but I feel very awkward in using this book. It give too less information for me in many topics.

Comment: I guess my level of understanding is somewhere between complex variable and complex analysis. So I guess a less rigorous complex analysis book is better for me, could you recommend one ? I would like to try Conway, but I am not sure about how hard and rigorous it is.